# How to reset master password in Odoo v10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

how to reset master password in odoo10 to create new database.
issue:- database creation : access denied....

Answer (score 2):

You can change it from configuration file.

In configuration file you can set **admin_passwd** and restart your odoo server.

ex:

> ```
> [options]
> admin_passwd = mysupersecretpassword
> db_host = 192.168.1.2
> db_port = 5432
> db_user = odoo
> db_password = pwd
> dbfilter = ^mycompany.*$
> ```

You can follow odoo below link.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/deploy.html

This may help you.